# Force Outlook to show TabReadMail instead of TabNewMailMessage

Tags: c#, outlook, vsto

I'm developing a VSTO plugin for Outlook that puts a button in the TabNewMailMessage ribbon tab to allow you to send your message via my secure API instead of by email.  Everything works wonderfully, except there is a pesky problem I am chasing into a corner, and I can't solve.

I need the message to behave more like a sent message, and less like a saved draft of a message.

I began by saving my messages into the default sent items folder in Outlook, but I couldn't organize my messages alongside Outlook sent items because mine have no 'sent date'.

So I moved to saving them in a custom folder, but now they show the TabNewMailMessage instead of TabReadMail, like other sent messages.

Ultimately, I need these messages to be saved in Outlook somewhere without having actually been sent, but appearing and behaving as sent messages.  Best outcome would be to force the TabReadMail behaviour, second best might be disabling the send group on TabNewMailMessage.  I've tried some approaches found on SO, but my GetInspector() has no CommandBars.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to create the message in the sent state. Outlook Object Model does not allow you to do that directly - `MailItem.Sent` property is read-only.

The only workaround that seems to work (at least so far) is to create a new `PostItem` object (it is created in the sent state), set its `MessageClass` property to `"IPM.Note"`, save it. You can then reopen the message using `Namespace.GetItemFromId` - since you reset the message class, you will get back the regular `MailItem` object. The icon might still be wrong, so you would need to reset/delete it using `MailItem.PropertyAccessor` (you need the `PR_ICON_INDEX` property, its DASL name is `"http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x10800003"`).

If using [Redemption](http://www.dimastr.com/redemption/) (I am its author) is an option, your can set [RDOMail](http://www.dimastr.com/redemption/RDOMail.htm).`Sent` property before the message is saved for the very first time (MAPI limitation):

```
  set Session = CreateObject("Redemption.RDOSession")
  Session.MAPIOBJECT = Application.Session.MAPIOBJECT
  set Folder= Session.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderSentMail)
  set Msg = Folder.Items.Add
 
  Msg.Sent = true
  Msg.Unread = false
  Msg.Recipients.AddEx "Fake User", "someuser@fake.domain.com",  "SMTP"
  Msg.Subject = "fake sent message"
  Msg.Body = "test body"
  Msg.ReceivedTime = #2014/08/01 5:00PM#
  Msg.SentOn = #2014/08/01 5:00PM#
  Msg.Sender = Session.CurrentUser
  Msg.SentOnBehalfOf = Session.CurrentUser
 
  Msg.Save
```